# Connecting Twitter to Business Facebook page just spins

Tags: facebook, twitter, facebook-apps, facebook-app-settings

I am trying to connect my Twitter Account to my business Facebook page.  I followed Twitter's instructions to connect to Facebook ala https://support.twitter.com/articles/31113-using-twitter-with-facebook#.

I feel like I've done everything, but when I uncheck the 'Post retweets...' and 'Post to my facebook...' and then check the 'post to my facebook page' it just sits there and spins:

[image: TwitterFacebookConfig_img]

Am I missing something?  I've tried this in both firefox and chrome.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

While this isn't much of an answer, the problem resolved itself.  Not sure what happened, but perhaps cookies and/or cache needed to be cleared.